# In html textarea tag automatic takes 4 spaces

Tags: html

When click middle position of the HTML textarea tag , it automatic takes 4 space. I want,dont take any space in textarea.

```html
    <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="chief_complaints" class="form-control"   value="">
    </textarea>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: *it automatic takes 15 space* Huh? None for me.

Comment: Again, no space characters for me. Or are you talking `padding`?

Comment: click middle of the textarea box

Comment: If you deliberately **put** spaces in between the opening and the closing tag, what do you expect? The textarea works as it is supposed to. Also, this has nothing to do with Bootstrap, and cannot be solved using Bootstrap or CSS.

Comment: What about the answer given did you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard, the `textarea` element does not support the `value` attribute, instead of that everything between `<textarea>`  and `</textarea>` belongs to the value of the text area. To get rid of any spaces and newlines you have to write `<textarea></textarea>` without anything between the start and the end tag.

Comment: Noteworthy: It does, of course, have a `value` property.

Comment: @connexo I changed to the wording, I hope that it is now clear what I meant.

Comment: Newlines don't seem to cause any problems. Neither do tab characters.

Comment: @connexo did you ever verify that claim? In this [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5g1c8xkq/), the spaces and newlines will be there and also tabs should work.

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>[DON NOT USE BREAK LINES AND SPACES HERE, LET IT BE BLANK]</textarea>`

For example:

`<textarea rows="2" cols="10">Your Content</textarea>`